# É possível modificar o comentário do header de um file em PyDev

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, comentários, pydev

Tenho andado a experimentar diversos IDEs para o Python, por exemplo `PyCharm` ou o mesmo `IDLE`. Agora estou a tentar usar o `PyDev` como plug-in para `Eclipse`, e até estou bem a gostar. Gostaria de saber se é possível trocar ou modificar o comentário do header de default.

Por exemplo, se eu crio uma classe, ele dá isto:

```
'''
Created on Dec 8, 2014

@author: nbro
'''

class MyClass(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(self, params):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
```

Gostaria de mudar o comentário inicial em modo que se reflita sempre nos meus projectos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vá em **Window** clique em **Preferences** > **PyDev** > **Editor**. Procure por **(Code) Templates** e altere os valores listados em **Comments**.